# How to use different pseudo-absences for different models in biomod2

Tags: biomod2

I have generated two sets of pseudo-absences externally. First set is equal to presences and to be used with random forest. The second set is 10,000 and to be used with maxent. How do I use this in biomod2?

Thanks for your help.